# Can a unique key with 3 columns act as a foreign key for one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am having a classic case of `one-to-many` relation.

Currently I'm having an SQL like given below with *no relation* whatsoever defined between two tables (`my_table` and `comments` table):

```
SELECT
    (SELECT
            COUNT(1)
        FROM
            comments
        WHERE
            comments.gl_account = my_table.gl_account
                AND comments.document_number = my_table.document_number
                AND comments.division = my_table.division) AS comments_count,
    my_table.division,
    my_table.gl_account,
    my_table.document_number,
    my_table.reviewer_group,
    my_table.id
FROM
    my_table;
```

It is returning `comments` count in addition to other columns from `my_table`.

I want to correct this SQL by using `1-to-many` relationship; that from `my_table` (one) to `comments` table (many).

How do I do this? Note that there are three columns used by inner query above.

Sample SQL snippet hint appreciated, thank you!

Comment: How come they have "no relation whatsoever" and still compare their columns in the subquery WHERE clause?

Comment: I mean they are logically storing same data. But no constraints defined as such e.g. a foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, those three columns are unique in `my_table`, so you can declare them as a primary key:

```
create table my_table (
    . . . ,
    primary key (division, gl_account, document_number)
);
```

Then you can declare a foreign key relationship:

```
create table comments (
    . . . ,
    foreign key (division, gl_account, document_number) references my_table (division, gl_account, document_number)
);
```

Comment: Should a unique work instead of primary key?

Comment: @Akshay If it is unique, what's the issue implementing the PK?

Comment: @AkshayLokur . . . MySQL will recognize the foreign key reference with just `key` -- *any* index.  The standard specifies `unique` or `primary key`.  But you should use the primary key; foreign key references are one of the main reasons to define them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Makes sense. The PK has been assigned to another column and I will need to change it now. Possible to give example of how can I get the comments count though?

Comment: @AkshayLokur . . . Wrong approach.  Use the primary key in second table.

Comment: Ah it is my framework (Laravel Eloquent) which does not support composite primary keys. I think I need to resort to unique keys in this case...

Comment: @AkshayLokur . . . I support avoiding composite primary keys.

Comment: Well then you suggest doing that in your answer above. Sorry a bit confusing.